# Ban certain "news" sources from Google Now

Tags: google-now

I want to ban articles from certain news websites from appearing as cards in my Google Now feed. I think that this is a very relevant problem even for others, given how many "news" sources really are "misinformation" sources.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Google Now settings are managed from a mobile app not from a web application.

Comment: @Rubén Google now is informed by almost everything one does in the google ecosystem.

Comment: I know that. How does it makes the question be on-topic in the Web Applications site? IMHO Google Now is not a web site that behaves like an application. Reference [help/on-topic]

Comment: Because a large part of the Google ecosystem consists of web-applications like Gmail, google search, e.t.c.

Comment: I still think that this question should be closed. Take a look to http://android.stackexchange.com/ as the question could be on-topic there.

Comment: Google Now is reachable from the desktop (see http://www.google.com/landing/now/#getitchromewin) but it's still not really a web app. You also can't do any customization there; for that you need a smartphone.